# Can someone explain how this code works when asked to return a number?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

i got some exercises from my professor. So the exercise was to make to classes: **Question** and **Test** so on the Test class i got a method where i need to represent the points of each question when i ask e.g **i call num 3 and each question that is 3 points will appear** and if there are no nums that i called it should return **null**  but i can't understand how this part of code works? If someone could explain it to me i would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Code:

```
public Question[] returnPoints(double nP){
    if(index == 0)
        return null;

    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
    //Question[] questions
        if(questions[i].getPoints() == nP)
            count++;
    }

    if(count ==  0)
        return null;

    Question[] temp = new Question[count];
    int idx = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        if(questions[i].getPoints() == nP)
            temp[idx++] = questions[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of tags here, but no language tag? Tagging language makes it easier for people who know the language to find the question and also affects syntax coloring of the code.

Comment: Try to explain better your problem

Comment: Was this something you got from your professor? or IS this something you made? And if you made this yourself, do you have to work with an array ?

Comment: No the professor made the code !

Comment: The problem is that i don't understand why he used two for-loops. And why he created the temp array ?

Comment: The reason he created a temp array is because an array has a fixed size. So first he counts how many questions meet the condition. After that he creates an array with the correct length. After that he fills up the new temp array with the questions that meet the conditions and returns it.

The question is why would you want to use an array is this situation... I would ask him this question because in this case i would return a list and do every thing in 1 loop.

Comment: Because he's an old-school `C` programmer who wants to teach arrays before teaching Collections. But no one in their right mind would write such code except to demonstrate how much work is involved in writing code that relies too heavily on arrays.

Comment: I thought about it too but i got no choice but to learn it :\  Thank you very much for your time and response :))

Comment: I will  and i will respond his answer the day i ask him :)

Comment: @LodeVlaeminck Here:

Comment: If you just use the array I do not see any way appropriate.
The reason why it worked so, that for me it's okay, is not known in advance that many of the questions are eligible, therefore the first loop is nothing more than to determine the size of the array.

Comment: If you use any structure as LinkedList or something similar then you can have and do with a for loop without problem.
As structures as ArrayList or Vector, will not perform the job if really we want with the use only "a for loop" because the structures of managing data through the array and every time there instead of "increase" string to "factor" given ,

Comment: We know that the array does not increase, but the establishment of a new-born of the old with the plus factor. If the factor is 1, then when we want to and also entered a new element (eg even a question) of no place, need to be created a new range, the copied data exists and at the end we Will add a new element. Notwithstanding a do its job this method of copying or use cash as Arrays.copy ... there is for loop.

Comment: sorry dude dont understand ...